# Bootstrap nested layout - Column breaks down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

as I am new to Bootstrap and working on a test site which requires nested column layout.
my code is as under

```
            <html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
                <body>
                <div class="container">
                <div id="page" class="row">

            <header id="branding" role="banner" class="span12">
                <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                Menu 
                </nav>
                </header>

            <section id="primary" class="span9">
            <div id="content" role="main">
                <h1 class="entry-title">Some Title</h1> 
                <div class="entry-meta">
                Some Info
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

            <div class="row meta-info">

            <div class="post-image span3">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                image
                </ul>
            </div><!-- .post-image -->

            <div class="post-intro span4">
                some intro text
            </div><!-- .post-intro -->

            <div class="post-desc span2">
                some more info
            </div><!-- .post-desc-->

            </div><!-- meta info-->


            </section>
            </div><!-- #content -->

            </div><!-- row -->
            </div><!-- container -->
            </body>
            </html>
```

I see every think ok on a large display, but on a screen 1152x864, post-desc on span2 will break down and appears at the bottom of span4.

what I need that this should remain responsive and should adjust with browser re-size.

is my code correct? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Please help.

Regards
SAQ

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row meta-info">
```

shoud be

```
 <div class="row-fluid meta-info">
```

supposing your container has a max-width value on it, it should work.